# Slow Gremlin Query returning 21K node properties

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

Having an issue running the following gremlin query:

```
g.V().has('[label]', 'Customer').valueMap(true, 'customer_id')
```

I'm using a mixed index on '[label]', however, the valueMap step is still synchronous in its execution.  This results in slow query performance and doesn't scale well as the graph grows.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('[label]', 'Customer').valueMap(true, 'customer_id').profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
JanusGraphStep([],[[label].eq(Customer)])                          21113       21113        1991.216     9.49
    \_condition=([label] = Customer)
    \_isFitted=true
    \_query=[([label] = Customer)]:node_label_mixed
    \_index=node_label_mixed
    \_orders=[]
    \_isOrdered=true
    \_index_impl=search
  optimization                                                                                 0.039
  optimization                                                                                 0.908
  backend-query                                                                                0.000
    \_query=node_label_mixed:[([label] = Customer)]:node_label_mixed
  backend-query                                                                                0.000
    \_query=node_label_mixed:[([label] = Customer)]:node_label_mixed
  backend-query                                                                                0.000
    \_query=node_label_mixed:[([label] = Customer)]:node_label_mixed
  backend-query                                                                                0.000
    \_query=node_label_mixed:[([label] = Customer)]:node_label_mixed
  backend-query                                                    21113                    5589.282
    \_query=node_label_mixed:[([label] = Customer)]:node_label_mixed
PropertyMapStep([customer_id],value)                               21113       21113       18982.089    90.51
```

Is there a better way to formulate this query so that it can run in parallel in order to get better performance fetching all node properties at once?

Comment: Hi there. Quick question why are you using a mixed index? Since you only querying against a single vertex property a [composite index](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html#_composite_index) is much simpler and should be faster.